# Retrieve the decision table in readable format from ODM Decision Center using Java code/API

Tags: jrules, ibm-odm

I need to extract the contents of a decision table in a `readable/tabular` format from the IBM ODM Decision Center Business Console using Java and ODM APIs provided.

This has to be an automated process and hence I cannot use the existing `Import/Export` feature provided by ODM.

Does anyone have any sample code or have implemented such a requirement?

Version: `ODM 8.10.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Query the decision center for the decision table (see [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP76_8.10.x/com.ibm.odm.dcenter.custom/topics/tpc_custdc_usingapi.html) for instructions)

Step 2:

```
                if (rule.getType().equals("brm.DecisionTable")) {
                        IlrDecisionTable dTable = (IlrDecisionTable) rule;
                        IlrDTController controller = IlrSessionHelper.getDTController(session, dTable, new Locale(dTable.getLocale()));
                        String tableHtml = IlrDTHelper.getHTMLTable(controller, false, false);//getHTMLTable(IlrDTController controller, boolean showEmptyRow, boolean includeCSS)
                        ...
                    }
```

Comment: Please accept the answer so others may find it too.

Answer (score 0):

if you synchronise your Rule Designer rules with Decision Center, you can use REST API to extract your Decision Table as an excel file from Decision Center.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/odm/8.10?topic=api-rest

[image: REST API export Excel]

Hope this helps,
Emmanuel